# Least square estimation in nonlinear regression

Tags: regression, parametric

Consider the following Model:

$Y_i = f(\theta, x_i) + e_i$

Where $\theta$ is the unknown d-dimesional parameter, and $e_i$ are some nice stochastic errors so maybe identical and normal distributed. $x_i$ are deterministic designpoints in $[0,1]$

Does someone know what optimal rate can be achieved for some parametric Estimator? So for example
let $\theta_n$ denote the LSE, Then i am intrestet in

$E||\theta_n-\theta||^2\lesssim $ ???

with $||\theta_n-\theta||^2:=\sum_{k=1}^d |\theta_{n,i}-\theta_i|^2$

Comment: Do you know how to do this if the model is $Y_{i}=x_{i}^{T}\theta+\epsilon_{i}$?  If the $\epsilon_{i}$ are small relative to the curvature of $f$, then you can linearize around the optimal parameters $\theta^{*}$ and analyze using that approximate linearization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you give some references?

Comment: This is discussed in many texts on nonlinear regression such as Seber and Wild’s Nonlinear Regression.